# Next/prev wordpress user

Tags: php, wordpress

To get a clear view of what I mean, each time you create a wordpress user it gets it's own ID number. This number is always unique. When you delete a user the ID will be unreachable (call the permalink via ID). And when you create a user, a brand new ID is being used.

My author.php page functions as a simple about me page. I'm trying to create a 'previous user' and 'next user' button. Currently this is created using a ACF custom field with manually setting the said users. The issue is when a user is being deleted or new one being created, the acf fields need to be reconnected.

Is there a way to have this automated? (not using acf, just php) So when I create a new user the prev/next buttons show the prev/next user's id?

I know similar can be done for posts, but I can't find anything that works for users.

```
//author.php - for example on user ID 3
<h2>My profile with some nice text</h2>

// Link to previous user - 2? if deleted 1
Previous user button
<a href="<?php get_author_posts_url($author_id); ?>
">Prev Button</a>

// Link to next user - 4? if deleted 5, 6, 7, etc.
<a href="<?php get_author_posts_url($author_id); ?>
">Next Button</a>
```

Comment: In PHP, you can get a user list from wp_users table, then you can manipulate the user list as you want. It is automatic with some lines of PHP code (less than 10 lines).

Comment: I see, so to get the list of users it would be best to use [get_users()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/)? Is there a way of isolating the previous and next item in that array?